# Get MAX value of a group for each month TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have a TSQL query which gives a max value of the trend data for the given result set. I would like to get this data based on each month's result. (I have  a datetime column in the result set ). If I select data for three months it has to give this vaules for each month. Right now it looks for the max values and give the same result for all the months.

Below is the expression i use to get the trend result. It's part of select statement with number of other columns.

```
select col1, col2, sampledatecollected, (Select MAX(AvailMemSlope) FROM SlopeCTE) * MetricID + (Select MAX    (AvailMemIntercept) FROM InterceptCTE) AS AvailMemTrend
```

I think i might need to do something like this but given the expression i'm little confused as to how to get the desired results

```
select name, max(value)
from tbl1
group by name
```

CPUTrend id the data i get from the expression i specified in the first query.

sample data:

```
 Date        AVGCPU MAXCPU CPUTrend
8/22/2016   20      40     44
8/23/2016   20      40     44
8/24/2016   20      40     44
8/25/2016   20      40     44
9/22/2016   20      50     44
9/23/2016   20      50     44
9/24/2016   20      50     44
```

Expected result:

```
Date        AVGCPU MAXCPU CPUTrend
8/22/2016   20      40     32
8/23/2016   20      40     32
8/24/2016   20      40     32
8/25/2016   20      40     32
9/22/2016   20      50     44
9/23/2016   20      50     44
9/24/2016   20      50     44
```

Right now all i get is 44 as it's the maximum value.

Comment: please show some sample data  and expected result

Comment: @TheGameiswar I have added few more details in the question. Please verify

Comment: please post current sample data

Comment: @TheGameiswar done.

Comment: the question is still not clear,please take some time to see how to improve question..here is a good place to start..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a subquery:

```
with t as (
      select col1, col2, sampledatecollected,
             (Select MAX(AvailMemSlope) FROM SlopeCTE) * MetricID +
             (Select MAX (AvailMemIntercept) FROM InterceptCTE) AS AvailMemTrend
      from ??  -- the SQL in your question is incomplete
     )
select year(sampledatecollected), month(sampledatecollected),
       max(AvailMemTrend)
from t
group by year(sampledatecollected), month(sampledatecollected)
order by year(sampledatecollected), month(sampledatecollected);
```